# How to determine the Java version needed for different versions of DRACs

Tags: java, dell-poweredge, drac

We have two different server machines in our workplace, they are:

1. Dell - PowerEdge T620 - runs drac 7 (ver 1.35.35)
2. Dell - PowerEdge 2950 - runs drac 5 (ver 1.65)

Is it possible for me to determine which Java version is needed for each of the machines, in order to use the Virtual Console?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this information in the release notes.

For T620 (iDrac firmware version 1.57.57)

> To launch Virtual Console using Java plug
>   - in, only JavaWebStart versions 1.5, 1.6, and 1.7 from Sun (Oracle) is supported. Any other versions or any other installations are not
>   supported.

For PE2950 :

> JRE version 1.6.0 or later needs to be installed on the management
>   station.

Comment: thanks a lot @sfk, where are the release notes available? where can I find them?

Comment: The release notes are available along with the idrac update download (http://support.dell.com/). BTW i recommand that you update the idrac in the T620 for a better user experience with the virtual console.